# Skip line while debugging in Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a feature in Google Chrome developer tools that would allow skipping a line without it being executed while debugging, in a similar way that it can be done in Visual Studio?

One workaround I can think of is 'live editing' the code by wrapping the line in

```
if(false){ //line to be skipped }
```

But this is not the most convenient workaround that I would have to do after every refresh. **Is there a built-in or faster, better way of doing this?**

Comment: No, control transfer is not supported in DevTools. Please file a feature request at http://crbug.com/new

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Done. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=6&q=skip%20line%20while%20debugging&id=382904&thanks=382904&ts=1402405661

Answer (score 73, accepted):

No, and is [not going to happen.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=6&q=skip%20line%20while%20debugging&id=382904&thanks=382904&ts=1402405661#hc6)

Last comment from dev says:

> We're going to hold off on this feature for now. It's complexity is high and it's not common enough a workflow. One could also just comment out the lines and hit ctrl-s to get the same effect, pretty much. Status: WontFix –

The workaround is to comment out the line you want to skip and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: Hi Matas, any idea why its not going to happen?

Comment: @CHash_Mike if you would click on link last comment from dev says: `We're going to hold off on this feature for now. 

It's complexity is high and it's not common enough a workflow.

One could also just comment out the lines and hit ctrl-s to get the same effect, pretty much.


Status: WontFix 
`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed updte Matas!!

Comment: So completely recompiling the whole block and trying to match up the instruction pointer is easier than advancing the instruction pointer to the next statement?  Bizarre, but perhaps becuase its javascript, and interpreted line-by-line

Comment: In case anyone else comes here for the same reason I did, this doesn't work if you are using the "Pretty Print" option to view your code in dev tools.

Comment: It also doesn't work, rather obviously, if you're debugging javascript via chrome://inspect on a mobile device against deployed code, say for example, within a cordova build.

Comment: One idea around this problem is to build in debug variable to control the flow of execution, since values of variables CAN be adjusted in the debugger.